# Keras: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on a GAN based problem and I am getting this issue where the gradients are not visible. I was hoping if someone can help me here. I have two main piece of codes that might be able to help you identify the issue. First piece of code loads the data in the variables.

```html
training_images = []
target_images = []

for image in images:
    a_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(Augment_img_dir, image),0), (128,128))/255
    
    lsri_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(LSRI_img_dir, image),0), (128,128), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)/255
    
    hsri_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(HSRI_img_dir, image),0), (128,128))/255
    
    img_train = [a_img, lsri_img]
    img_train = np.asarray(img_train)
    img_train = np.moveaxis(img_train,0, -1)
    
    training_images.append(img_train)
    
    target_images.append(hsri_img)

training_images = np.asarray(training_images)

target_images = np.asarray(target_images)

train_imgs, test_imgs, train_targets, test_targets = train_test_split(training_images, target_images, 
                                                                     test_size=.20, random_state=42)

batch_size = 8
train_img_batch = []
target_img_batch = []
len_imgs = len(train_imgs)
start = 0
temp_train = []
temp_target = []
for i in range(len_imgs+1):
    if i%batch_size == 0 and i>0:
        train_img_batch.append(np.asarray(temp_train))
        target_img_batch.append(np.asarray(temp_target))
        temp_train = []
        temp_target = []
    if i != len_imgs:
        temp_train.append(train_imgs[i])
        temp_target.append(train_targets[i])

train_img_batch = np.asarray(train_img_batch)
target_img_batch = np.asarray(target_img_batch)
```

The second piece of code is the actual train function where I am getting the error.

```html
batch_size = 8
lr = 0.0001
G_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)
n_epoch  = 100
iterations = 13500
def train():
    G = Generator((128,128,2)).generator()
    D = Discriminator((128,128,1)).discriminator()
    
    g_optimizer_init = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    g_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    d_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    mse_loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    n_step_epoch = round(n_epoch // batch_size)    
    
    G_Loss_file = open("g_loss.txt",'w')
    
    
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        step_time = time.time()
        for step, lr_patchs in enumerate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_img_batch)):
            if lr_patchs.shape[0] != batch_size: # if the remaining data in this epoch < batch_size
                break
            
            hr_patchs = target_img_batch[step]
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                #tape.watch(G.trainable_weights)
                fake_hr_patchs = G(lr_patchs)
                fake_hr_patchs = np.reshape(fake_hr_patchs, (8,128,128))
                mse_loss = mse_loss(fake_hr_patchs, hr_patchs)
                
            grad = tape.gradient(mse_loss, G.trainable_variables)
            g_optimizer_init.apply_gradients(zip(grad, G.trainable_variables))

        print("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.2f}s, mse: {:.2f} ".format(
                epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss))
            
        G_Loss_file.write("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.2f}s, mse: {:.2f} \n".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss))
    G_Loss_file.close()
    
    ## adversarial learning (G, D)
    Loss_file = open("loss.txt",'w')
    n_step_epoch = round(n_epoch // batch_size)
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        step_time = time.time()
        for step, lr_patchs in enumerate(train_img_batch):
            if lr_patchs.shape[0] != batch_size: # if the remaining data in this epoch < batch_size
                break
                
            hr_patchs = target_img_batch[step]
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                fake_patchs = G(lr_patchs)
                fake_patchs = np.reshape(fake_patchs, (8,128,128))
                logits_fake = D(fake_patchs)
                logits_real = D(hr_patchs)
                
                
                #d_Loss_int = Intensity_Loss(logits_fake, logits_real)

                d_loss1 = tl.cost.sigmoid_cross_entropy(logits_fake, tf.zeros_like(logits_fake))
                
                d_loss = -np.log(d_loss1) #+ 0.1*d_Loss_int
                
                g_gan_loss = 1e-3 * tl.cost.sigmoid_cross_entropy(logits_fake, tf.ones_like(logits_fake))
                mse_loss = tl.cost.mean_squared_error(fake_patchs, hr_patchs, is_mean=True)
                
                
                g_loss = mse_loss + g_gan_loss
            
            grad = tape.gradient(g_loss, G.trainable_weights)
            #print(grad, len(G.trainable_weights))
            g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, G.trainable_weights))
            grad = tape.gradient(d_loss, D.trainable_weights)
            d_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, D.trainable_weights))
        
        print("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.3f}s, g_loss(mse:{:.3f},  adv:{:.3f}) d_loss: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss, g_gan_loss, d_loss))
            
        Loss_file.write("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.3f}s, g_loss(mse:{:.3f},  adv:{:.3f}) d_loss: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss, g_gan_loss, d_loss))
        
        if epoch!=0 and ((epoch%10 == 0) or (epoch == n_epoch-1)):
            
            G.save_weights("Gan_Weights/g_training_20_noise_no_contrast.h5")
            D.save_weights("Gan_Weights/d_training_20_noise_no_contrast.h5")
        
    Loss_file.close()
```

The line where I get the error is following:

```html
g_optimizer_init.apply_gradients(zip(grad, G.trainable_variables))
```

and the error is following:

```html
No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_392/kernel:0', 'conv2d_392/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_312/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_312/beta:0', 'conv2d_393/kernel:0', 'conv2d_393/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_313/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_313/beta:0', 'conv2d_394/kernel:0', 'conv2d_394/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_314/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_314/beta:0', 'conv2d_395/kernel:0', 'conv2d_395/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_315/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_315/beta:0', 'conv2d_396/kernel:0', 'conv2d_396/bias:0', 'conv2d_397/kernel:0', 'conv2d_397/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_316/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_316/beta:0', 'conv2d_398/kernel:0', 'conv2d_398/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_317/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_317/beta:0', 'conv2d_399/kernel:0', 'conv2d_399/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_318/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_318/beta:0', 'conv2d_400/kernel:0', 'conv2d_400/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_319/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `numpy` operations in several places inside the scope of `GradientTape`, for example in the line

```
fake_hr_patchs = np.reshape(fake_hr_patchs, (8,128,128))
```

Replace all `numpy` functions inside `GradientTape`'s scope with their `tensorflow` equivalents. For example, the above line becomes:

```
fake_hr_patchs = tf.reshape(fake_hr_patchs, (8,128,128))
```

Comment: Hello, I just did that and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot it was really quick and helpful

Comment: It is working like a charm now. Thanks a lot. I have a followup question. Though it works the processing is not taking place on GPU and it is taking place on my CPU? Is there any suggestion for that?

Comment: Is the package installed `tensorflow-gpu`, and does your machine have the required CUDA and CuDNN versions?

Comment: Yes I am able to run a different model on GPU but when I run this model it does not allocate it to GPU.

Comment: Run `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` on a terminal while the model is running and check the output for some time. It'll let you know whether the problem is with the pipeline or the model.

Comment: So I tried it. Looks like the notebook is able to call the GPU but does not allocate operations to the GPU. All the operations move to CPU. Could it be possible that since the image is read with CV2 and then I am processing images using numpy that is leading to this issue?

Comment: Yes. Basically, preparing a batch is taking much longer than running it.

Comment: I used 'tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)' to identify where my program is running but it logs show that all operations are of CPU and not on GPU. Is there a way to fix it ?