# Unable to run training session on GPU: Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I tried to read images using CV2 and store them in a numpy array as shown in the code below. I do not wish to use ImageDataGenerator from Keras to read the images.

```html
for image in images:
        a_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(Augment_img_dir, image),0), (128,128))/255

        lsri_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(LSRI_img_dir, image),0), (128,128), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)/255

        hsri_img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread( os.path.join(HSRI_img_dir, image),0), (128,128))/255

        img_train = [a_img, lsri_img]
        img_train = np.asarray(img_train)
        img_train = np.moveaxis(img_train,0, -1)
        

        training_images.append(img_train)

        target_images.append(hsri_img)

    training_images = np.asarray(training_images)

    target_images = np.asarray(target_images)

    train_imgs, test_imgs, train_targets, test_targets = train_test_split(training_images, target_images, 
                                                                         test_size=.20, random_state=42)

    batch_size = 8
    train_img_batch = []
    target_img_batch = []
    len_imgs = len(train_imgs)
    start = 0
    temp_train = []
    temp_target = []
    for i in range(len_imgs+1):
        if i%batch_size == 0 and i>0:
            train_img_batch.append(np.asarray(temp_train))
            target_img_batch.append(np.asarray(temp_target))
            temp_train = []
            temp_target = []
        if i != len_imgs:
            temp_train.append(train_imgs[i])
            temp_target.append(train_targets[i])
```

I coded a GAN model training session as described in the code below and expect the model to train on GPU. However, the training is taking place on CPU.

```html
batch_size = 8
lr = 0.0001
G_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)
n_epoch  =50
iterations = 13500
def train():
    G = Generator((128,128,2)).generator()
    D = Discriminator((128,128,1)).discriminator()
    
    g_optimizer_init = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    g_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    d_optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    mse_loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    n_step_epoch = round(n_epoch // batch_size)    
    
    G_Loss_file = open("g_loss.txt",'w')
    
    
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        step_time = time.time()
        for step, lr_patchs in enumerate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_img_batch)):
            if lr_patchs.shape[0] != batch_size: # if the remaining data in this epoch < batch_size
                break
            
            hr_patchs = target_img_batch[step]
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                #tape.watch(G.trainable_weights)
                fake_hr_patchs = G(lr_patchs)
                fake_hr_patchs = tf.reshape(fake_hr_patchs, (8,128,128))
                mse_loss = tl.cost.mean_squared_error(fake_hr_patchs, hr_patchs, is_mean= True)
                
            grad = tape.gradient(mse_loss, G.trainable_variables)
            g_optimizer_init.apply_gradients(zip(grad, G.trainable_variables))

        print("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.2f}s, mse: {:.2f} ".format(
                epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss))
            
        G_Loss_file.write("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.2f}s, mse: {:.2f} \n".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss))
    G_Loss_file.close()
    
    ## adversarial learning (G, D)
    Loss_file = open("loss.txt",'w')
    n_step_epoch = round(n_epoch // batch_size)
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        step_time = time.time()
        for step, lr_patchs in enumerate(train_img_batch):
            if lr_patchs.shape[0] != batch_size: # if the remaining data in this epoch < batch_size
                break
                
            hr_patchs = target_img_batch[step]
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                fake_patchs = G(lr_patchs)
                fake_patchs = tf.reshape(fake_patchs, (8,128,128))
                logits_fake = D(fake_patchs)
                logits_real = D(hr_patchs)
                
                
                d_Loss_int = Intensity_Loss(logits_fake, logits_real)

                d_loss1 = tl.cost.sigmoid_cross_entropy(logits_fake, tf.zeros_like(logits_fake))
                
                d_loss = tf.add(-tf.math.log(d_loss1), 0.1*d_Loss_int)
                
                g_gan_loss = 1e-3 * tl.cost.sigmoid_cross_entropy(logits_fake, tf.ones_like(logits_fake))
                mse_loss = tl.cost.mean_squared_error(fake_patchs, hr_patchs, is_mean=True)
                
                
                g_loss = tf.add(mse_loss, g_gan_loss)
            
            grad = tape.gradient(g_loss, G.trainable_weights)
            #print(grad, len(G.trainable_weights))
            g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, G.trainable_weights))
            grad = tape.gradient(d_loss, D.trainable_weights)
            d_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, D.trainable_weights))
        
        print("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.3f}s, g_loss(mse:{:.3f},  adv:{:.3f}), d_loss: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss, g_gan_loss, d_loss))
            
        Loss_file.write("Epoch: [{}/{}], time: {:.3f}s, g_loss(mse:{:.3f},  adv:{:.3f}), d_loss: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch, n_epoch, time.time() - step_time, mse_loss, g_gan_loss, d_loss))
        
        if epoch!=0 and ((epoch%5 == 0) or (epoch == n_epoch-1)):
            
            G.save_weights("Gan_Weights/g_training_20_noise_no_contrast.h5")
            D.save_weights("Gan_Weights/d_training_20_noise_no_contrast.h5")
        
    Loss_file.close()
```

The model is not running on GPU and I want to utilize my GPU
This is how I call the function to train the model

```html
with tf.device("/device:XLA_GPU:0"):
    train()
```

Comment: Yes, using numpy arrays to store images does not prevent the GPU being used. You have a XY problem.

Comment: what do you mean by XY problem?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Sounds good. What kind of additional info can I provide? Also you can look at this link to get a better idea about the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278045/keras-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable/65278100?noredirect=1#comment115406212_65278100

Comment: You need to describe the actual problem in this question, not describe what you think the problem or solution is.

Comment: I have updated the question to hopefully solve the XYProblem you pointed out.